# How to create ColorAnimation without fade effect

Tags: wpf

I want to change the background color of a rectangle to green for 1 second than change it back to black.  I want to simulate a light being on or off - I dont want to fade the color in.  The code below does what I want except it fades from black to green and vice versa.  I definately dont want sleep on the UI thread..........

```
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation { From = Colors.Black, To = Colors.LightGreen, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), RepeatBehavior= new RepeatBehavior(1), AutoReverse=true };
SolidColorBrush activityLight = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
ActivityIndicator.Fill = activityLight;
this.RegisterName("activityLight", activityLight);
ActivityStoryboard = new Storyboard();
ActivityStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "activityLight");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613802.aspx):

```
var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
colorAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(
    new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(Colors.Green, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0d)));
colorAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(
    new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(Colors.Black, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d)));

ActivityIndicator.Fill.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colorAnimation);
```